# Present ImagePickerView causing crash

Tags: ios, swift, nsexception, photolibrary

Here is my code, a simple class with a view created in storyboard that contains a button to present the imagePickerView. The imagePickerView gets presented and then the app crashes with `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class ImageSelectionView: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func openPhotoLibrary(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}




}
```

Can't figure out where this is going wrong, any help would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: did you ask for permission for the photos?

Comment: @MikeG Try my answer and let me know Is it work or not ?

Comment: Check My answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing photo library, you need to put `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` in your application's `.plist` file with some description,

like this shown in image

[image]

And porticularly in your code, you have written code to present the same imagePicker twice as showing below.

```
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:
```

Hence I suggest to keep one, may be
 `present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)`

OR

```
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Hope it helps.

Happy coding ...

Comment: The problem was calling `present(view)` twice, i totally overlooked that thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: i accepted answer, what is the purpose of an upvote?

Comment: @MIke, up vote is to let the others know this is the appropriate answer, along with accepted, more up vote, make other users confidence to use the answer.

Comment: Makes sense, I agree

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong when U calling imagepicker delegate method then a viewcontroller is preseted to pick image So replace

```
present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

WITH

```
self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and in you r not showing image in your imageview

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    "YOUR IMAGEVIEW".image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code your problem will solve easily.

```
@IBAction func openPhotoLibrary(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Picture", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        if(  UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera))
        {
              let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
              myPickerController.delegate = self
              myPickerController.sourceType = .Camera
              self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else
        {
              let actionController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Camera is not available",message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
              let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
                    //Just dismiss the action sheet
              }
              actionController.addAction(cancelAction)
              self.presentViewController(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }

        actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)
        //Create and add a second option action
        let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Camera Roll", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self;
            myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)

        //Present the AlertController
        self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

        "YOURIMAGEVIEW".image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```